# Errors with Angular 9 "ng new" on Windows

Tags: angular

I'm trying to learn the current version of Angular, v9. And I'm running on Windows 10, though I wouldn't have thought that would matter for a client-side technology.

The tutorials say I should start with `npm install -g @angular/cli`, so I do that.  It prints a bunch of warnings about several dozen packages, but otherwise appears to work (I've never used npm before, so I don't know what to expect).

The next step is to create a project with "ng new", so I try to do that, but it fails with a weird error:

```
C:\temp\ngtest>ng new my-first-project

C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng:17
var version = process.versions.node.split('.').map(part => Number(part));
                                                        ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3

C:\temp\ngtest>
```

I really didn't expect a syntax error at this point, and I have no idea what to do about it.

Google didn't turn up any hits on this particular error, but several similar errors suggest tracking down package incompatibilities or dependencies.  I have no idea how to do that, and I guess I thought the whole point of npm was to take care of stuff like that for me.

Help?

P.S. Just to establish a baseline, imagine a clever guy, decent programmer, who has been teleported from the year 2000 to 2020.  Programming is still programming, of course - but the infrastructure is bewildering and frankly incomprehensible.  There are at least a dozen layers of stuff that "everybody" knows so thoroughly that they don't even think about it any more.

Comment: what versions of `node` and `npm` are you using?  (`node --version`, `npm --v`)

Comment: Node version is v0.12.2, npm is 2.7.4

Answer (score 0):

Try installing node version latest i.e. 12.16.2 via nodejs.org/en and then again perform npm install -g @angular/cli. This should solve your problem

Comment: Node version is v0.12.2, npm is 2.7.4, don't know how to check typescript version.

Not sure what you mean by "If you have not coded anything" - I've been programming for 40+ years, but I'm getting this error trying to create the project, so I haven't written any angular code yet.

Comment: Hi Mark, i just was asking that you had not written code within the project which is obvious b'cz you are just setting up the project(my bad). Try installing node version latest i.e. 12.16.2 via https://nodejs.org/en/  and then again perform npm install -g @angular/cli. This should solve your problem.

Comment: OK, installing node.js got me a little farther. The "ng new" now creates a couple dozen files, then spins for about a minute or two "installing packages" (god only knows what it's doing to my poor PC), before finally dying because I don't have "git" installed.  Git is a version control system, and reportedly a hard one to learn.  Do I seriously have to learn how to install and use git before I can write "hello world" in angular?

Comment: Not necessary to install git. Are you following some particular setup guide? Can you share the link or the error.

Comment: I must have closed the tab, but I've seen several that seemed to say basically the same thing: install angular (npm install -g @angular/cli), then create a project (ng new xxx).  The error is simply "'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file".

Comment: I went ahead and installed 'git', and now "ng new" runs a little further - it gives errors with my git user name or something, but at least I can see my "hello world" size program.

Comment: Disturbingly, the project directory has over 57,000 files in over 5,000 directories, adding up to a total over almost 350 megs - for an "empty" project!  The programming world has gone completely insane, but I guess it's what we all have to deal with.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Yes that is the batteries included angular thing. If you need any assist feel free to ask questions. Also do up tick my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With help from "sunny", I finally got it working (or at least close enough for my purposes).  To save future readers from having to dig through the comment trail, I'll document the steps here:

1. Install node.js
2. Install git
3. Install angular/cli
4. Open a NEW command window, so the environment variables will be set properly
5. ng new my-project

In my case it still gives errors about my git identity not being set properly, but that's not important for my purposes so I'm not going to worry about it for now.